# 503 Server Error On Google App Engine Backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Been working on this all day, hopefully someone can help. I'm trying to use a Backend on google app engine to run a process that will kick off 100,000 tasks

any time i try to call a backend service url i get

**Error: Server Error
The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.**

On the app Engine Console, my backed is shown as started after running appcfg backends update

Running appcfg /war backends start / stop works fine without error

my backends.xml:

```
<backends>
    <backend name="maint">
        <class>B2</class>
        <instances>1</instances>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
            <public>true</public>
        </options>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

what am i not doing??

Comment: Do you perhaps have a servlet mapped on `/_ah/start`?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your backends, or shown us any code - how can we possibly help?

Comment: @NickJohnson - Hi Nick, thanks for helping. I didn't post any code because even a simple httpservlet gives me this error.  Maybe I'm missing something about backends, but If I map a servlet in my web.xml to appid.appspot.com/hello  and that service just does a println of "hello world" - and it works.  Then I browse to backendname.appid.appspot.com/hello - shouldn't it work the same only using the backend instance? I get the Server Error mentioned. What am I missing?